# how does this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

```
//1  
var object1 = function(o){

   // some code

};  

//2  
var object2 = new object1({

   method1: //some code  
   method2: //some code  
   method3: //some code

});

//3


document.onkeydown=function(e){     
  var eventKey = e.keyCode || e.charCode;   
  var sel = Coverflow.selected;  
  if(eventKey == 39 || eventKey == 37) {  
        if(eventKey == 39) sel++;  
      else if(eventKey == 37) sel--;  
      sel = sel.limit(0, Coverflow.getListLength() - 1);  
      Coverflow.select(sel);
    }  
}
```

well, my question are:

1. what happens when object1 is created, what does the = function() part mean?
2. is object2 pointing to object1. is that assignment creating a inheritance?
3. if possible can someone explain what going on in document.onkeydown(). the code is for a coverflow effect. also this function is not been called anywhere else in the program then how does it get executed?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when object1 is created, what does the = function() part mean?

Functions, in JavaScript, are first class objects. They can be passed around and assigned like any other function.

> Is object2 pointing to object1? Is that assignment creating an inheritance?

No. object2 is an *instance* of object1. This is like treating object1 as a class definition.

> how does `document.onkeydown` get executed?

When a key is pressed down, an event will be fired. Code in the document object (which is provided by the browser) listens for that event and calls that function (if it exists).

[MDN has some documentation on how events work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) if you want more details.

Comment: what is the difference between making a object using the 1 and 2 statements with making a object like var obj = { method1 : ...}

Comment: object1 is a function rather than being a plain object

Comment: object2 inherits properties from object1 as well as whatever the function does to the new object

Answer (score 0):

1 - its a function named `object1`, defined at runtime, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

2 - new instance of function with a parameter passed to it (referenced as 'o' in function declaration)

3 - function is bound to `onkeydown` event so it gets executed every time key is pressed on document, more info [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/introduction-browser-events)

Comment: Strictly speaking, 2 should read "... with *a parameter* passed to it.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot you are of course right, correction comming up :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have a notion of class, but it is possible to have the similar behavior. So I will call objects/functions that may be instantiated classes.

1. `object1` is some kind of class defined by constructor, `function(){...}` part is a constructor of that class.
2. `object2` is a reference to instance of `object1` class, which was instantiated by calling constructor of `object1` class with 1 parameter, which itself is an object.
3. `onkeydown` is a reserved property of DOM objects for handlers of `keydown` event. Once this event is fired by browser it is handled by relevant function (if it is exists)